# Group by and count data with one query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table structure in database

[image]

I want to get number of likes **for each** post by counting **post** field in **likes** table and display it for every post using `foreach` loop.

**My question is**

Is there a way i can do this with one query with `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` tables and not create multiple queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.title, p.content, count(l.id) as likes_count
from posts p
left join likes l on l.post = p.id
group by p.id, p.title, p.content
```

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me what is p and l?

Comment: These are aliases for the tables `posts` and `likes`. You define the like this: `...from posts p` or `...from posts as p`. They are not need in this case, but make the query shorter

Comment: Is there a way that i can union that query with this `SELECT * FROM posts` so i can get all post data and likes in one `foreach` loop. Or can i combine two `foreach` loops.

Comment: That is a little too vague. Ask another detailed question if you can't find an anwer.

Answer (score -1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bca8ee/1

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(l.id)
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN likes l
ON l.post = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Yes, this works in MySQL. But I wouldn't call that a feature. It is missleading to not group by or aggregate the columns you select. And it does not work in other DB engines. Especially newbies find that confusing.